# Can someone explain to me how the following JS script works

Tags: javascript

The script below works fine but i just dont understand how it works especally the following section:  Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);. can somebody please explain the how the whole script works. thank you.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);

function guessnum() {

    var guess = document.forms["form1"].num.value;
    if (guess == num) {
        alert("Great you Guessed! How did you know that?");
    }

    if (guess < num) {
        alert("No your number is too low!");
    }

    if (guess > num) {
        alert("No your number is too  high");
    }

}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: You **should** start with this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random.

Comment: yes..please do a little R&D before posting here

Comment: no offense, but seriously, what research did you put before posting this ? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
```

is calculating an integer between 0 and 100 randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() just selects any random number and returns it.

Math.floor gives you a rounded, nearest lower value without any decimals. E.g.

```
Math.floor(14/6)
```

will give 2  as the rounded quotient

Rest of the code is almost self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns a value between 0 and 1. So multiplying it with `101` results in a value between 0 and 101. As the guessing game requires the decimals removed, the value is rounded down using `Math.floor()`.

So the actual value is in the range 0 to 101 (or 0 *up to* 100).

Comment: @Amberlamps a value **between** a maximum and minimum indeed is never the maximum. So basically your answer is the wrong one, as you mean 'an integer from 0 *up to and including 100*. But this an an language discussion/issue, which is off-topic here!

Comment: When I say *between 0 and 100* I mean every integer between 0 and 100 including 0 and 100.